# GCR push very slow

Tags: docker, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, ubuntu-16.04, google-container-registry

Since a few days, the `gcloud docker -- push` command has become terrible slow, sometimes taking up to 10 minutes to push a simple change (like a change in default `CMD` in the `Dockerfile`)

I saw there was a post a while back ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032236/speed-of-gcloud-docker-push?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)), but sadly without any good reason why it's slow and/or how to resolve it.

As a side node, I'm building the images using Jenkins on Ubuntu 16.04 using `gcloud` version 197.0.0

Does anyone else experience the same issues?

Comment: Where is this Jenkins server deployed? Is it within the GCP(or any other local machine)? Have you tried pushing the image from an other instance in the same network? And also you are right, 'gcloud docker' will not be supported for Docker client versions above 18.03. For the latest versions you can use '[gcloud auth configure-docker](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/configure-docker)'

Comment: I also found [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032236/speed-of-gcloud-docker-push?noredirect=1&lq=1) discussing the slow docker push and docker daemon restart may help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be hitting [docker/cli#840](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/840).

What version of docker are you using, and does updating to 18.03 fix your issue?

Comment: tbh, I didnt update to 18.03 due to the following reason: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/support/deprecation-notices. Here it states the following: `As of April 3rd, 2018, gcloud docker is not supported for Docker client versions above 18.03.`

Comment: 18.03 will be supported, but 18.04 and above will not